# Switching functionality on and off in a Scheduled Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

To illustrate how to do leader election with Apache Zookeeper I've created an straightforward application and I would like to have to threading part of the application reviewed.
I've created a simple class (`Speaker`) which outputs an unique identifier to a file on a regular interval. I've implemented the `Runnable` interface and start it with a `ScheduledExecutorService` with a fixed delay like this:

```
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(speaker, 0, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The `Speaker` class also implements a `Listener` interface so it can register itself to a `Monitor` (running in a separate thread, communicating to the Zookeeper server)  which can enable or disable the output to the file.

My review question (besides general code review):  Is this the best way to start and stop functionality in a scheduled thread?

Speaker & Speaker Server:

Complete project: https://github.com/cyberroadie/zookeeper-leader

Code explanation: http://cyberroadie.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/implementing-leader-election-with-zookeeper/

```
public class Speaker implements Runnable, NodeMonitor.NodeMonitorListener {

    private String message;
    private String processName;
    private long counter = 0;
    private volatile boolean canSpeak = false;

    public Speaker(String message) throws IOException, InterruptedException, KeeperException {
        this.message = message;
         this.processName = getUniqueIdentifier();
    }

    private static String getUniqueIdentifier() {
        String processName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
        String processId = processName.substring(0, processName.indexOf("@"));
        return "pid-" + processId + ".";
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (canSpeak) {
                handleTask();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void handleTask() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(message + ": " + counter++ + " " + processName + "\n");
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void startSpeaking() {
        this.canSpeak = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stopSpeaking() {
        this.canSpeak = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProcessName() {
        return processName;
    }
}
```

Speaker Server:

```
public class SpeakerServer {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpeakerServer.class);

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private static NodeMonitor monitor;

    private static void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("program [message] [wait between messages in millisecond]");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        long delay = Long.parseLong(args[1]);

        Speaker speaker = null;

        try {
            speaker = new Speaker(args[0]);
            monitor = new NodeMonitor();
            monitor.setListener(speaker);
            monitor.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(speaker, 0, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        logger.info("Speaker server started with fixed time delay of " + delay + " milliseconds.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also look at using a fixed thread pool. That way, if one thread becomes blocked for some reason, say the disk became full, the threads would wait in a queue until the blocked thread terminated. That way you wouldn't loose any unique id's or run into memory problems if too many threads became blocked.

Hope that helps,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider stopping the scheduler (or canceling the task) on a `stopSpeaking` call and restarting it on a `startSpeaking` call (or resubmitting the `Runnable`). I'm not familiar with Zookeeper, I don't know anything about the typical usage, so if stop/startSpeaking calls arrives often it won't be the best solution but it seems cleaner if there are long breaks between `stopSpeaking` and `startSpeaking` calls.

A few notes about the code:

1. Consider using SLF4J to log the exceptions too instead of `printStackTrace()`.
2. Close the `BufferedWriter` in a `finally` block:

   ```
   final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
   try {
       ...
   } finally {
       out.close();
   }
   ```
3. `System.exit` isn't a nicest way to stop an entire application, especially hidden in a `catch` block of a `run` method. I'd rethrow the `IOException` as a `RuntimeException` (or a `RuntimeException` subclass):

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       if (!canSpeak) {
           return;
       }
       try {
           handleTask();
       } catch (final IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }
   ```

   then use the `ScheduledFuture` of `scheduleWithFixedDelay` to wait for the `RuntimeException`:

   ```
   final ScheduledFuture<?> speakerFuture = 
       scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(speaker, 0, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   logger.info("Speaker server started with fixed time delay of " + delay + " milliseconds.");
   try {
       speakerFuture.get();
   } finally {
       scheduler.shutdown();
   }
   ```

   Disclaimer: I don't like the usage of `RuntimeException` here, but unfortunately the `scheduleAtFixedRate` accepts only `Runnable` objects (not `Callable`s which could throw any `Exception`).

   Please notice the [guard clause](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) also.
4. I'm not completely sure that `ScheduledExecutorService` guarantees whether scheduled task will always run in the same thread or not. (I suppose it does not.) Furthermore, the `counter` field in the `Speaker` class could be synchronized properly due to volatile piggybacking but I'd use a defensive strategy here and use `AtomicInteger` for the counter to make it less error-prone.
5. I'd check `null`s in the constructor of `Speaker`. [checkNotNull from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) is a great choice for that.

   ```
   this.message = checkNotNull(message, "message cannot be null");
   ```

   (Also see: *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)
6. [SLF4J supports `{}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J), use that:

   ```
   logger.info("Speaker server started with fixed time delay of {} milliseconds.", delay);
   ```